# Algorithm puzzle: minimum cost for allow all persons standing on a line to communicate with each other

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have a algorithm design puzzle that I could not solve.

The puzzle is formulated like this: There are N persons standing on a number line, each of them maybe standing on any integer number on that line. Multiple persons may stand on the same number. For any two persons to be able to communicate with each other, the distance between them should be less than K. The goal is to move them so that each pair of two persons can communicate each other (possibly via other people). In other words, we need to move them so that the distance between any neighboring two persons is smaller than K.

Question: What is the minimum number of total moves? It feels like this falls into greedy algorithm family or dynamic programming. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: What constitutes a move? Can we move a person on the number line anywhere else in one move?

Comment: You can move a person anywhere, the distance change caused by that move is the cost. And we want to minimize the summation of all such cost

Comment: Without having tried, I think an A* algorithm could work quite well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm There is a good heuristic on the minimal number of moves needed to get to a solution. Just look how often and by how much the constraint is violated between neighbouring people.

Comment: @Henry the A star algorithm seems more relevant for pathfinding, I don't quite follow how it can be used for this problem

Comment: Yes, consider each configuration a node and the moves are the edges between the nodes. Start at the node corresponding to the original configuration and find the shortest path to any allowed configuration.

Answer (score 1):

We can do the following in `O(n)`:

Calculate the cost of moving all people to the right of person `i` towards person `i` at an acceptable distance:

```
costRight(A[i]) = costRight(A[i+1]) + (A[i+1] - A[i] - k + 1) * count of people to the right

K = 3;  A = { 0,  3, 11, 17, 21}
costRight = {32, 28, 10,  2,  0}
```

Calculate the cost of moving all people to the left of person `i` towards person `i` at an acceptable distance:

```
costLeft(A[i]) = costLeft(A[i-1]) + (A[i] - A[i-1] - k + 1) * count of people to the left

K = 3;  A = { 0,  3, 11, 17, 21}
costLeft  = { 0,  1, 13, 25, 33}
costRight = {32, 28, 10,  2,  0}
```

Now that we have cost from both directions we can do this in `O(n)`:

```
minCost = min(costRight + costLeft) for all A[i]
minCost = min(32 + 0, 28 + 1, 13 + 10, 25 + 2, 33 + 0) = 23
```

But sometimes that's no enough:

```
K = 3;  A = { 0,  0,  1,  8,  8}

      carry:     -2  -4       3
costLeft  = { 0,  0,  0, 11, 11}

      carry: -3   5      -2
costRight = { 8,  8,  8,  0,  0}
```

The optimum is neither 11 nor 8. Test the current best by moving towards the greatest saving:

```
move 1 to 2, cost = 1

K = 3;  A = { 0,  0,  2,  8,  8}

      carry:     -2  -2     -10
costLeft  = { 0,  0,  0, 10, 10}

      carry: -2          -2
costRight = { 6,  6,  6,  0,  0}

minCost = 1 + min(0 + 6, 0 + 6, 0 + 6, 10 + 0, 10 + 0) = 1 + 6 = 7
```

Not quite sure how to formularize this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a greedy algorithm written in Java, but I don't know if it gives the optimal solution in every case. Also it is more a proof of concept, there is some room for optimizations.

It is based on the fact that two neighbouring persons must not be more than K apart, the next neighbour must not be more than 2K away and so on. In each step we move the person that "violates these constraints most". The details of this calculation are in method `calcForce`.

```
package so;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] position = new int[] {0, 0, 5, 11, 17, 23};
        int k = 5;

        solve(position, k);
    }

    private static void solve(int[] position, int k) {
        if (!sorted(position)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("positions must be sorted");
        }
        int[] force = new int[position.length];
        int steps = 0;
        while (calcForce(position, k, force)) {
            int mp = -1;
            int mv = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < force.length; i++) {
                if (mv < Math.abs(force[i])) {
                    mv = Math.abs(force[i]);
                    mp = i;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("move %d to the %s%n", mp, force[mp] > 0 ? "right" : "left");
            if (force[mp] > 0) {
                position[mp]++;
            } else {
                position[mp]--;
            }
            steps++;
        }
        System.out.printf("total: %d steps%n", steps);
    }

    private static boolean calcForce(int[] position, int k, int[] force) {
        boolean commProblem = false;
        Arrays.fill(force, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < position.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < position.length; j++) {
                int f = position[j] - position[i] - (j - i) * k;
                if (f > 0) {
                    force[i] += f;
                    force[j] -= f;
                    commProblem = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return commProblem;
    }

    private static boolean sorted(int[] position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < position.length - 1; i++) {
            if (position[i] > position[i+1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```